# ID getting lost during delayed job

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, delay, illuminate

I'm dispatching a delayed job that should created some entries in the database:

```
$userId = Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier() : null;
 $job = new DelayedAddPeopleJob($event, $userId);
 dispatch($job)->delay(DelayedAddPeopleJob::DELAY);
```

After 15 minutes DelayedAddPeopleJob is executed and in there im creating entries in the DB if they do not exist.

```
AutoAddHistory::firstOrCreate([
                AutoAddHistory::MATRIX_ID_COLUMN => $matrixId,
                AutoAddHistory::ROLE_ID_COLUMN => $ppr->getRoleId(),
                AutoAddHistory::PERSON_ID_COLUMN => $ppr->getPersonId(),
                AutoAddHistory::CREATED_BY_COLUMN => $this->placedBy,
 ]);
```

In this instance the placedBy is the userId passed to DelayedAddPeopleJob. However when the entries appear in the database after those 15 minutes the CREATED_BY is NULL in the database for some reason.

Am I doing something wrong? I tried to find a solution or similar problem but can't. Tried accessing it via magic method instead on const and it did not help.

Comment: Did you check whether `$userId` was already `null` when you called `DelayedAddPeopleJob($event, $userId)`? What debugging have you already done, if any?

Comment: Where does the `$this->placedBy` come from when it is set? Why isn't it set otherwise?

Comment: Do you think it might be because some model events that trigger when saving the created model and createdBy is taken right there and then when saving after 15 minutes delay? But since it's delayed 15 minutes the model event receives null as createdBy rather than using the placedBy

Comment: why you don`t use db to save parameters.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I debugged it locally using xdebug and removing the delay. When the delay got removed and in my .env I added my Id as permanent user It got saved in the DB properly. So it happens only when the delay get's applied but I want to retrain myself from building the test env too much.

Comment: @HoseainSanadgol Im using model which I want to save also first or Update is very handy to prevent creating new entries. However in this case is messing things up. Im currently in process of testing new solution

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's the userId passed in the constructor, is just that the name changes from userId to placedBy in the job

Answer (score 1):

I tried one solution that seems to worked. The code that specifies $userId works properly. The issue was model events that happened when saving the model after the 15 minutes delay. Inside the UserStamps trait

```
 if (is_null($model->{$createByColumn}) && !empty($createByColumn)) {
        $model->{$createByColumn} = $auth->getAuthIdentifier();
    }
```

$auth->getAuthIdentifier() was returning null on model event after delay and it overwrites the placedBy attribute. I solved it by:

```
  $autoAddHistory = AutoAddHistory::firstOrNew([
                AutoAddHistory::MATRIX_ID_COLUMN => $matrixId,
                AutoAddHistory::ROLE_ID_COLUMN => $ppr->getRoleId(),
                AutoAddHistory::PERSON_ID_COLUMN => $ppr->getPersonId(),
                AutoAddHistory::CREATED_BY_COLUMN => $this->placedBy,
            ]);
            $autoAddHistory->setAuth($authUser);
            $autoAddHistory->save();
```

Where the $authUser = new NullUser(['id' => $this->placedBy]); This solved the problem and entries. Rather than using firstOrUpdate I used firstOrNew and adjusted the  system auth user and saved the model manually.

Comment: Why does it makes to check `!empty($createByColumn)` AFTER `is_null($model->{$createByColumn})`?

Answer (score 0):

**Job can't contain a user session data**.

For this reason, your condition `$userId = Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier() : null;` always goes to false and return null, you have to call the userId in another way.

You can store the userID at the parent record table and fetch from here once you need.

Also make sure `CREATED_BY` column **fillable** difined at your model.

Comment: The user ID is being set when the job is dispatched, not in the job itself.